# Commenting on Questions and Answers

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)

I am not able to comment on many questions and answers. I am able to comment on stackoverflow but not in a few other sites of stackexchange, why is it so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You [need to have 50 rep](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment) to be able to comment. That is the rule for all Stackexchange sites, except Meta's where you can comment with 1 rep.

Comment: I can comment on meta and the questions/answers posted by me but not anywhere else because of having reputation less than 50?

Comment: @RishabhPoddar yes, exactly